# Manifest merged failed

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, build.gradle

I am trying execute my android react native project and I am getting this error:

> :app:processDebugManifest
>   /Users/me/project/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   Error:
>           Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>           is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>           Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information
>   about the manifest merger.
>
> :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.2) from
>   >     [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
>   >         is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>   >         Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to override.

This is my Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/> 
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "project.com"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 27
        versionName "5.1.1"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile (project(':pushwoosh-react-native-plugin'))
    {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    compile project(':react-native-google-analytics-bridge')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile("com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0") {
        force = true
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Anybody help me to fix the error? Thank you!

Comment: Add `tools:replace="android:value"` in your AndroidManifest.xml, to resolve this error. As suggested, in warning.

Comment: @Heisen-Berg Both conflicting manifests are part of a library. Therefore they can not be edited. I would try to remove one of the libraries to resolve the problem or at least use both libraries in the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Write tools:replace="android:value" in your AndroidManifest.xml inside application tag and if you are facing different version issue so please go to project.properties file inside android platform folder and correct the version.